how to know the behavior of a sentence using NLP
I am trying to build the NLP model, using that nlp model i want to know the intention of text sentence.
Hi,
I am trying to build the NLP model, using that nlp model i want to know the intention of text sentence.
For Ex- If the sentence is like "Create an incident for not able to fill the timesheet".
so in above example how we know the intention of the sentence using nlp model

First you should have data of such sentences. and get it annotated manually. By annotation i mean it to mark it as positive sentiment or negative sentiment.
you can replace positive or negative with anything depending upon your usecase. Once the data is ready then do some data cleaning post that create embedding(try count vectorizer) of the data. then split your data into 80:20 ratio and use 80% of the data to train the model (Try logistic regression). After the training evaluate your model using remaining 20% of the model.
And if you do not want to annotate the data then you can try out pretrained model from hugging face such as roberta etc.
